# More complicated URL's in WebAPI controller than basic CRUD

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

All the examples of WebAPI I have seen show how to have a basic CRUD setup with a controller. For example the controller below shows a controller for `campaigns` in my application:

```
public IEnumerable<CampaignModel> Get()
{
    return _campaignService.GetAll();
}

public CampaignModel Get(int id)
{
    return _campaignService.GetByID(id);
}

public void Post(CampaignModel campaign)
{
    _campaignService.Create(campaign);
}

public void Put(CampaignModel campaign)
{
    _campaignService.Update(campaign);
}

public void Delete(int id)
{
    _campaignService.Delete(id);
}
```

This is all well and good, and I end up with a few nice endpoints in the following format:

- GET campaigns/
- GET campaigns/{id}
- POST campaigns/{campaign}
- PUT campaigns/{campaign}
- DELETE campaigns/{id}

However, I now want to extend the api further and add the following endpoints:

- POST campaigns/send
- POST campaigns/schedule/{date}

Is it possible to have these as part of the same controller as the CRUD actions above? Or do I have to add other controllers to and then set up a route for each of these endpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out "Routing by Action Name" over [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

public class CampaignsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void send();

    [HttpPost]
    public void schedule(DateDto date);
}
```

will map to “api/campaigns/send” and “api/campaigns/schedule”

Comment: sweet as a nut mate - exactly what I wanted

Comment: it all boils down to the RPC vs REST discussion